# Which of the following option are true about open and closed sets (C.S.I.R Dec -2015)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Question :

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ and $f: R^2 \mapsto \mathbb R^2$ be any function. Then

1. $f^{-1} (G_1 \cup G_2 ) = f^{-1} (G_1) \cup f^{-1} (G_2)$
2. $f^{-1} (G_1^c) = (f^{-1}(G_1))^c$
3. $f(G_1 \cap G_2) = f(G_1) \cap f(G_2)$.
4. If $G_1$ is open and $G_2$ is closed, then $G_1 + G_2  =\{ x + y : x \in G_1 , y \in G_2 \} $ , is neither open nor Closed.

for 1) , 2) , 3)

Any $f(x) \in G_1 \cup G_2$ , then either $f(x) \in G_1$ or $f(x) \in G_2$.Similarly we can prove 2) and 3), So 1), 2) ,3) are true .

4) Let $G_1 = \{(0,0)\}$ and $G_2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 : x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$ ,Then $G_1$ is closed and $G_2$ is open and $G_1 +G_2$ is open

Please see my solution, If you find any mistake, then correct me. Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is wrong;

Comment: 1 and 2 are correct

Answer (score 0):

For 1, you say "any $f(x)\in G_1\cup G_2$ then either $f(x)\in G_1$ or $f(x)\in G_2$."  Strictly speaking that only proves $f^{-1}(G_1\cup G_2)\subset f^{-1}G_1\cup f^{-1}G_2$.

The statement of 4) also sounds odd to me where you say "$G_1+G_2$ is neither open nor closed."  Your example does not show this, since in that example $G_1+G_2$ is open. Wouldn't $G_1+G_2 = \cup_{x\in G_2} (G_1+\{x\})$, a union of open sets and thus itself open?

Comment: @ Forgot : In 1) Converse is also true, it is very easy                                        I have doubt on fourth option , i have  given a counter example shows that there is a closed set $G_1$ and open set $G_2$ whose sum is open.